# php set time delays after input attempts

Tags: php

Question is related with brute force attacks.
If user enters incorrect password, php records in mysql datetime of the attempt. And in case of incorrect password I need that the user can make next attempt only after certain time (1-2 seconds).
As i understand php sleep is not good, because it does not prevent bots to make requests?

What would be solution (to set time delay without php sleep)?

Comment: sleep() or any other function cant be bypassed by bots. but why not add a CAPTCHA

Comment: I think you can do that by sessions too because I don't think bots clear cookies before each request.

Comment: Thanks for answers. You mean not to set time delay at all, only to add captcha after 2-3 failed attempts. If would not find solution for delay, would add captcha... or will try with sessions...

Comment: ...sorry, but read that bots ignore cookies. So sessions seems not solution

Answer (score 1):

You could add a sleep at the beginning of the file if the number of requests are high for that user.
Maybe add 1 second for every failed request in the past 24 hours or exit if that number reaches a certain threshold.

```
<?
//script to find when last requests were made
if($failed>2)
{
    sleep($failed+1);
}elseif($failed>10)
{
    exit;//or redirect
}
//the rest of the file

?>
```